# Standard way to encode an URL given a base URL and a Map<String,String> with parameters

Tags: java, url

we're looking for a standard way to encode a URL given a predefined base URL and a Map of parameters and values.
Ideally the method is declarated as something like

```
String constructURL( String baseURL, Map<String,String> parameters)
```

would work like the following snippet

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
params.put("p1", "v1");
params.put("p2", "v2");
String url = constructURL( "page.html", params);
```

and url would have the following value

```
"page.html?p1=v1&p2=v2"
```

Btw, we're using Apache Click with Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [URLCodec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec.html) from [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec) to create the url-encoded version of your parameters, and then loop on the parameters to create the query. Have a look at [the source of URLEncodedUtils class in Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#185) to see an example of what I explain.

Answer (score 2):

The JDK's `URLEncoder` should work for your use case. Like this :

```
String constructURL(String base, Map<String, String> params) {
  StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(base);
  if(params != null && params.size() > 0) {
  url.append("?");
  for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
      url.append(entry.getKey());
      url.append("=");
      url.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue()));
      url.append("&");   //not for the last one (but should be OK)
    }
  }

return url.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but building my own function is exactly what I was trying to avoid.